# My screen isn't working, how can I connect to an external monitor?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, macos

My MacBook Air 2015's screen isn't working so I can't see anything I'm doing. Is there a way to connect it to an external monitor?

EDIT:
The issue has been solved. I tried plugging it into a different monitor and must've done something differently because this time, it just showed up. After a little bit of trial and error, I got the screen to mirror and now it works perfectly with my normal one.

Comment: Are you able to start it up and verify that it has started? Are you able to login?

Comment: I can start it up and I'm logged in, I just don't know where to go from here because I can't see anything.

Comment: I'm pretty sure external displays are on by default.  <kbd>⌘-F1</kbd> should toggle between mirror and extended mode

Comment: I tried that and it didn't do anything

Comment: Wake it up with monitor attached and lid closed, then it will not use the internal display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can plug an external monitor into the Mini DisplayPort port (the Thunderbolt 2 port) on the MacBook Air. You'll need a Mini DisplayPort to DisplayPort cable, if your monitor supports DisplayPort.

For other monitors, you'll need an adapter, such as a Mini DisplayPort to DVI, VGA or HDMI adapter.

Comment: Yes and I have the cable for DisplayPort to DisplayPort, but there's a setting I need to change in order to allow the monitor to connect. I don't know how to change that setting without being able to see the monitor.

Comment: There's no settings necessary for connecting a monitor.

Comment: @Anmol Have you tried adjusting the brightness level on the laptop's internal display?

Comment: Sorry I should've clarified the mirroring is off and I need to turn it on but I can't see what I'm doing. And yes, the laptop's screen is broken but the laptop itself still turns on.

Comment: @Anmol What do you see on your external monitor currently? - It is black? - Does it show your desktop background? - Does it show a menu bar?